# KineticJS get all intersection

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I was working not so long ago with KineticJS and I have a problem.

I can draw circles (white, blue and red), and then I'll draw a polygon along the path of the blue circles.

But how do I find the coordinates, or at least something about the red circles. That is, about those who fall under the following polygons.

I tried using `getIntersection` but I do not understand what it returns. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance!!

http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/42/7gok.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your picture that all red and blue dots are positioned on a grid.

This means that the x and y of any dot are clamped to that grid (axis aligned)

I further assume that the blue dots define the outside of your polygon.

**So you want to see if any particular red dot is inside that polygon?**

Given these assumptions, any red dot is inside your polygon if it is surrounded by blue dots on all 4 vertical and horizontal sides

- Blue dot to left of red dot

  ```
  blueY==redY && blueX<redX
  ```
- Blue dot to right of red dot

  ```
  blueY==redY && blueX>redX
  ```
- Blue dot above red dot

  ```
  blueX==redX && blueY<redY
  ```
- Blue dot below red dot

  ```
  blueX==redX && blueY>redY
  ```

First, you need to be able to get all blue dots, so when you're creating blue dots be sure to assign them a name property of blue

```
name:"blue",
```

Then you can test any red dot using this function that checks if that red dot is surrounded by blue dots:

```
function isRedInPolygon(red){

    // get XY of the red circle
    var redX=red.getX();
    var redY=red.getY();

    // set up vars for results
    // these vars become true when blue dots are
    // directly up, down, left and right of the red dot
    var up=false;
    var down=false;
    var left=false;
    var right=false;

    // get all the blue dots into an array
    var blues=layer.get('.blue').toArray();

    for(var j=0;j<blues.length;j++){

        // get the XY of this blue
        var blue=blues[j];
        blueX=blues[j].getX();
        blueY=blues[j].getY();

        // test left/right
        if(blueX==redX){
            // left
            if(blueY<redY){ up=true; }
            // right
            if(blueY>redY){ down=true; }
        }

        // test up/down
        if(blue.Y==red.Y){
            if(blueX<redX){ left=true; }
            if(blueX>redX){ right=true; }
        }
    }

    // return true if this red dot is surrounded
    // by blue dots on all 4 sides
    return(up && down && left && right);
}
```

**To get a list of all red objects inside the polygon**

First, assign the name="red" to all red dots.

```
name:"red",
```

Then use this call to get an array of all red objects in the polygon.

```
var redsInside = listOfRedsInPolygon();
```

Using this function:

```
function listOfRedsInPolygon(){

    var reds=layer.get('.red').toArray();

    var redsInsidePolygon=[];

    for(var i=0;i<reds.length;i++){

        if(isRedInPolygon(reds[i])){
            redsInsidePolygon.push(reds[i]);
        }
    }

    return(redsInsidePolygon);
}
```

Disclaimer:  I have not tested this code...it might need some tweaking.

Comment: You have truly understood the question, but I need something else, I think so. I have all the blue points and I need to call a function that will check if there are any red dots, you have created a function that checks if a point (red) is inside the polygon, but how do I send her point red?

Comment: I have added to my answer to show how to get an array of all red objects in the polygon.